# Unable to subtract a table value via variable

Tags: php, sql

I can not get an SQL update statement to subtract a variable from a table value. Here is my code:

```
$_SESSION_Job101=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM job_101 WHERE job_101.username='$_SESSION_User'"));

mysql_query("UPDATE characters SET currenergy=currenergy-$_SESSION_Job101['ecost'] WHERE username='$_SESSION_User'");
```

`$_SESSION_Job101` is a perfectly valid result, as I pull from it on another page; I even pull the 'ecost' on said page. I also update currenergy this way in another script, except I use the number 1 instead of the variable. So I've narrowed it down to that variable.

It wouldn't matter that `$_SESSION_Job101` is the result from a second table (job_101), and that query is updating to the table characters, would it?

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated. Check MySQLI and PDO_MYSQL. SEE: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: DO you get any mysql_error ? Or it doesn't consider the value in $_SESSION_Job101['ecost'] ?

Comment: Yes, can you tell us if you have mysql_error? Another option is to run the generated SQL statements on the server and give us the outputs/errors.

Comment: I get a $1064 syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't have enough information, but since you don't perform ANY error handling or validation that SQL resultset is returned, it could be an error caused by issues such as:

- no rows returned in first query
- some other parsing issue not directly evident

I would propose that you use temporary strings and echo the actual SQL queries.
Continue by actually testing them with MYSQL (through workbench, queryviewer, or console) in order to see where and what the error is.

Also, it's not recommended to skip error checking and try to combine so many lines/steps into 2 lines.
Imagine the first query does not return any results for example...

**Debugging:**

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM job_101 WHERE job_101.username='$_SESSION_User'";
echo $query1."<br/>";
$_SESSION_Job101=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query1 ));
$query2 = "UPDATE characters SET currenergy=currenergy-$_SESSION_Job101['ecost'] WHERE username='$_SESSION_User'";
echo $query2."<br/>";
mysql_query($query2);
```

### Update

Based on your comment I suggest you try the following two options:

1) Add a space between the `-` and `$_SESSION_Job101['ecost']`.

2) If that doesn't work, change your string to:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE characters SET currenergy=currenergy-".$_SESSION_Job101['ecost']." WHERE  username='".$_SESSION_User."'";`
```

Comment: I do not get any mysql_error. I get an error "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql_query("UPDATE characters SET characters.currenergy=characters.currenergy-$' at line 1"

when I input just the mysql_query, replacing the variable $_SESSION_Job101['ecost'] with the number 1 (which actually works in another script of mine).

Comment: Aha, I'd suggest then you try adding a space between the `-` and `$`, and if that doesn't work, just the `.` concatenation operator instead of enclosing the variables within the String.

Comment: Neither of those worked. I just echo'd all values being accessed with no issues, so I feel it has to be a referencing issue with the variable. When I run the script, the page is just blank.

Comment: Add the following to the top of your php in order to display all errors: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` . The page is blank even though you echoed all the values?

Comment: I added the error reporting, page is still blank. Here is the entire page, minus my session_start and db variables:
// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$_SESSION_User=$_SESSION["myusername"];
$_SESSION_Name=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM characters WHERE username='$_SESSION_User'"));
$_SESSION_Job101=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM job_101 WHERE job_101.username='$_SESSION_User'"));

Comment: There is also the query and a header at the bottom. I've been able to echo the variable I am subtracing, and the username, so all values in the query are good. I am also able to echo any and all values in the arrays. When I include the query, however, the page goes blank.